# 3D-Rotation of a Rectangular Prism

Tags: java, 3d, processing, quaternions, rotational-matrices

I was messing around with processing creating some 3D objects, and I created a recursive method that I hope to generate a finger-like object with more degrees of freedom. The idea is that each segment, displayed as a box, generates a new segment so that it's bottom face is at the same location as the previous segment's bottom (shown below).[image: Segment Finger]

The problem is that when I try to rotate more than one axis (i.e. set both deltaX and deltaZ to be 0.3) my algorithm fails and I get something weird (show below). [image: Broken Segment Finger]

I used rotation matrices in order to try to calculate where the base of the new segment should be based on the old one and it works for only 1 rotating axis but fails on multiple (the math is in the if statement). I've seen posts about Quaternions, but I'm really just curious why my matrix math doesn't work, or if Quaternions are really so much better how I might implement them in my code. Thanks in advance!

```
void finger(float x, float y, float z, float rx, float ry, float rz, float r, 
float h){
  translate(x,-y,z);
  rotateX(rx);
  rotateY(ry);
  rotateZ(rz);
  translate(0,-h/2,0);
  box(r,h,r);
  translate(0,h/2,0);
  rotateZ(-rz);
  rotateY(-ry);
  rotateX(-rx);
  translate(-x,y,-z);
  if(r>10){
    finger(x+h*sin(rx)*sin(ry)*cos(rz)+h*cos(rx)*sin(rz),y-h*sin(rx)*sin(ry)*sin(rz)+  
    h*cos(rx)*cos(rz),z-h*sin(rx)*cos(ry),rx+deltaX,ry+deltaY,rz+deltaZ,r-4,h-5);
  }
}
```

[Edit: MCVE Below, includes my code for moving around in 3D space, and setup/variable initialization]
[Edit(2):MCVE Updated, change deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ for movement]

```
float deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ;
void setup(){
  deltaX=0;
  deltaY=0;
  deltaZ=0;
  fullScreen(P3D);
}
void draw(){
  noStroke();
  camera(-600, -400, -600, 0, -300, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  background(#51B6F5);
  directionalLight(255,255,255,0.5,1,0.5);
  directionalLight(255,255,255,-0.5,1,-0.5);
  box(400,10,400);
  tree(0,0,0,0,0,0,40,100);
}
void tree(float x, float y, float z, float rx, float ry, float rz, float r, float h){
  translate(x,-y,z);
  rotateX(rx);
  rotateY(ry);
  rotateZ(rz);
  translate(0,-h/2,0);
  box(r,h,r);
  translate(0,h/2,0);
  rotateZ(-rz);
  rotateY(-ry);
  rotateX(-rx);
  translate(-x,y,-z);
  if(r>10){
    tree(x+h*sin(rx)*sin(ry)*cos(rz)+h*cos(rx)*sin(rz),y-h*sin(rx)*sin(ry)*sin(rz)+h*cos(rx)*cos(rz),z-h*sin(rx)*cos(ry),rx+deltaX,ry+deltaY,rz+deltaZ,r-4,h-5);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just your `finger()` method?

Comment: Sure, added. It just includes my code for movement in 3D space, a box drawn in the draw method, and variable initialization.

Comment: I'm not trying to be obnoxious, but that's way too much code for an MCVE. Can you post a basic sketch with a simple `draw()` function that calls your `finger()` function? You don't need any of that extra user interaction stuff. When I try to get the bare minimum from your example, I end up with a black sketch. Just hardcode the variables you need to demonstrate the problem, and leave everything else out.

Comment: Sorry, not much experience with MCVEs, I think that should be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the rotations and translations you have **after** you draw each box are doing. They were causing your transformations not to really "stack". I could stare at them for another hour to come up with **why** they resulted in that behavior, but I'm not great at 3D stuff.

But think about it this way:

At the end of each call to `tree()`, you want your origin to be at the **top** of the box you just drew (the bottom of the box you're about to draw), and you want the rotations to "stack".

If you approach it that way, then you only need to do a few things- first you'll do your rotation (since the origin is already at the bottom), then you'll translate to the center to draw your box, then you'll translate to the top of your box, which is where you want the bottom of the next box to be. Probably easier just to show you the code:

```
void tree2(float x, float y, float z, float rx, float ry, float rz, float r, float h){

  //assume current origin is at bottom of box

  //rotate around bottom
  rotateX(rx);
  rotateY(ry);
  rotateZ(rz);

  //move to center
  translate(0,-h/2,0);

  //draw the box
  box(r,h,r);

  //move origin to the top of the box- the bottom of the next box
  translate(0,-h/2,0);

  //draw the next box
  if(r>10){
    tree2(x+h*sin(rx)*sin(ry)*cos(rz)+h*cos(rx)*sin(rz),y-h*sin(rx)*sin(ry)*sin(rz)+h*cos(rx)*cos(rz),z-h*sin(rx)*cos(ry),rx+deltaX,ry+deltaY,rz+deltaZ,r-4,h-5);
  }
}
```

That code seems to do what you want- it acts more like a "snake" with each section starting where the previous section ended.

By the way this is a fun little toy, I'd be curious to see what you end up doing with it!

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks almost exactly like what I wanted. However, I originally intended for all the angles to be the same between the segments, but as you can see if you rotate each time and increment the angles each time the angle gets bigger and bigger, which is why I had the reverse transformations there. This is definitely a great step forward though, and if I end up making something cool with it at some point, I'll make sure to come back and share it here! Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, it's an easy fix for the slight problem I mentioned above, just removing the rx,ry,rz from the recursive calls fixed it.

Comment: @Changming Yep, that's what I was about to say! Thanks for taking the time to make the MCVE, this was pretty fun to play around with.